# Making a circle out of . (periods)

Tags: javascript, math, drawing, geometry

I am trying to make a function that will draw a circle out of periods with only being given a starting `x` and `y` and a radius. Is it possible?
I would like to have the full code for it will an explanation for how it works; I've been trying this for 1 year now and I still can't fathom how it may be done.

Comment: Darn <500 rep! Anyways, [plz-send-me-teh-codez].

Comment: Should the circle be completely filled with periods, or do you only want the circumference? If it's just the circumference, does it all need to be text in a single div, or could you use any wacky combination of html elements?

Comment: no, i just need the outer ring. and if you need to, just make a bunch of document.writes haha, just as long as it would make a circle, it does not matter if it is inside a div

Comment: This would make for a nifty game of code golf.  Perhaps a bit too simple, though.

Comment: This sounds more like a homework problem to me.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the maths and even an example program in C:

<del>http://pixwiki.bafsoft.com/mags/5/articles/circle/sincos.htm</del> (link no longer exists).

And `position: absolute`, `left` and `top` will let you draw:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position

Any further questions?

Comment: +1 Nice to see an answer that nudges the OP in the right direction, as opposed to a copy/paste solution that they will not learn as much from

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. @Michael is essentially asking an ascii art problem and @Matti is answering in c and pixels. This is boring and off topic.

Comment: @Dave: Periods sort of look like pixels, don't they? And if you had actually taken a look at the C code, the syntax is almost identical to JS, and should be quite understandable.

Comment: @Matti, haha, I don't know where to start. I'll bury the fork at `void draw_circle () { int x, y;` looks nothing like Javascript.

Comment: no it is not, and w3 is a horrid place to look for tutorials, i learned that the hard way.

Comment: @Michael: W3 is the only reference I use nowadays. I don't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: w3 is good for some stuff but not the advanced stuff which is what i need, i bought a book for javascript, flash, and css and i went through every last chapter on each of them but none helped me even remotely solve my problem

Comment: Hey, @Matti, no hard feelings. I don't want to start name calling. You've got some good points. If you really want to draw circles, of course you'd want to use c. I was just pumped to answer a unique Javascript question. Peace my man.

Comment: @Dave: `void draw_circle() { int x, y;` is not dramatically different from `function draw_circle() { var x, y;`. The only difference is that the C declares types.

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for just the circumference, but it seemed easier to do a filled circle.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("jquery", "1");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawCircle(left, top, radius) {
        var pre = $("<pre/>").css({position: "absolute", top: top, left: left}).appendTo($("body"));
        var testSpan = $("<span> </span>").appendTo(pre);
        var cellWidth = testSpan.width();
        var cellHeight = testSpan.height();
        testSpan.remove();
        var diameter = 2 * radius;
        var dotArray = [];
        for (var row = 0; row <= diameter / cellHeight; row++) {
          for (var column = 0; column <= diameter / cellWidth; column++) {
            var cellDY = Math.abs(row * cellHeight - radius) - cellHeight / 2;
            var cellDX = Math.abs(column * cellWidth - radius) - cellWidth / 2;
            var distance = Math.pow(cellDY, 2) + Math.pow(cellDX, 2);
            if (distance < Math.pow(radius, 2)) {
              dotArray.push(".");
            } else {
              dotArray.push(" ");
            }
          }
          dotArray.push("<br/>");
        }
        pre.html(dotArray.join(""));
      }
      drawCircle(20, 20, 200);
  </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let me know which parts you'd like me to explain and I can elucidate. Good, fun question!

Comment: Alright, I know you guys don't like the question in the first place, hence the downvote. Honestly though, this is the only working code on the page that does what @Michael asked. It's really quite clever if I do say so myself. Give it a go.

Comment: Downvotes without comment are lame.

Comment: Maybe the downvoter didn't like your answer because it's copy-pasteable.

Comment: getting closer... but i said NO FILL, and it needs to look more like a circle than that haha but its pretty good

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Put the below code into an html file to see it in action.

A quick run through: The code generates an array of dots and spaces. It chooses to make a dot based on if the distance from the current x, y position to the center of the circle is less than or equal to the length of the radius via the distance formula ( http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm ).

```
<div id= "mydiv" style="font-family: monospace"> </div> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var x = 2; //starting x,y position of circle
    var y = 5; 
    var rad = 4; //radius of circle

    var width = 10; //width and height of display
    var height = 10;

    var dotArray = "";

    for (var i=0;i<width;i++){
        for (var j=0;j<height;j++){
            if (Math.sqrt( Math.pow(i-y, 2) + Math.pow(j-x, 2)) <= rad){
                dotArray += (".");
            } else {
                dotArray += ("&nbsp;");
            }
        }
        dotArray += "<br \>";
    }

document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = dotArray;
</script>
```

Comment: This is only drawing half circles at best for me in Firefox 3.

Comment: in chrome this does nothing except make a few lines of . nothing at all like a circle, what browser are u using, i need this to work fro chrome only.

Comment: You need to style it with `white-space: pre` as well.

Comment: Sorry; I had a slight glitch (replaced " " with "&nbsp;"). It now works correctly in Chrome (and probably other browsers as well).

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var e=0;
function a() {
    if(e<=7200){
        var f = (180-e)/2;
        var g = 90-e;
        var h = f-g;
        var j = Math.sin(g)*300;
        var n = Math.cos(g)*300;
        var m = 300-j;
        var newX = 900-m;
        var newY = 300+n;
        document.write("<p class=lol style=position:absolute;left:"+newX+";top:"+newY+">.</p>");
        e++;
    }
}

setInterval("a()", 1);
</script>
```

Comment: uh how do you make it in code like u guys did, it didnt show the whole thing

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> 
var e=0;
function a()
{
if(e<=7200){
var f = (180-e)/2;
var g = 90-e;
var h = f-g;
var j = Math.sin(g)*300;
var n = Math.cos(g)*300;
var m = 300-j;

var newX = 900-m;
var newY = 300+n;
document.write("<p class=lol style=position:absolute;left:"+newX+";top:"+newY+">.</p>");
e++;
}
}
setInterval("a()", 1);
</script>

Comment: Read the "How to Format" help on the right hand side when editing...

Comment: @Michael There's a [help document](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You click the code button, just to the right of the blockquote button you were already using

Comment: This did not work in IE for me, but it did work in Chrome!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var e=0;
function a() {
    if(e<=7200){
        var f = (180-e)/2;
        var g = 90-e;
        var h = f-g;
        var j = Math.sin(g)*300;
        var n = Math.cos(g)*300;
        var m = 300-j;
        var newX = 900-m;
        var newY = 300+n;
        document.write("<p class='lol' style='position:absolute;left:"+newX+";top:"+newY+"'>.</p>");
        e++;
        a();
    }
}
a();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [**Bresenham's circle algorithm**](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article767.asp).